# Resource Controller on Route of Site?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I use a resource controller on the route of my site:

```
Route::resource('/', 'TestController');
```

I hit the URL:

```
mysite.dev/some-slug-to-get-in-controller
```

And the show method doesnt work, just an error saying route doesnt exist.

I've checked the route list:

```
GET|HEAD  | /       | index   | TestController@index
POST      | /       | store   | TestController@store
GET|HEAD  | create  | create  | TestController@create
GET|HEAD  | {}      | show    | TestController@show
PUT|PATCH | {}      | update  | TestController@update
DELETE    | {}      | destroy | TestController@destroy
GET|HEAD  | {}/edit | edit    | TestController@edit
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this to get the desired effect

```html
Route::resource('/{slug}', 'TestController');
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Route pattern "/{slug}/{{slug}}" cannot reference variable name "slug" more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you want you need to point your resource controller to `some-slug-to-get-in-controller` then your new route would be `Route::resource('/some-slug-to-get-in-controller', 'TestController');`

In your code your pointing the resource controller to `/` route, not the route that you are expecting to see.

Comment: Yes, It has to be hardcoded, you can't refer to a dynamic route.